# CakePhp via Shell retorna o erro: class HelloShell could not be loaded

Tags: php, cakephp, ubuntu

Configurei e instalei tudo com relação o CakePhp para usar via linha de comando no ubuntu. criei e salvei o seguinte:

```
class HelloShell extends AppShell {
public function main() {
    $this->out('Hello world.');
}
}
```

Que é o código de exemplo deles. Mas quando executo via linha de comando é retornado esse erro, que não consegue carregar  a classe.

Ele fica em:

```
/home/ubuntu/cakephp/apps/almofadagram/Console/Command/HelloShell.php
```

E executo dali mesmo, mas como disse é retornado o erro:

```
Error: Class HelloShell could not be loaded.
```

Comment: Qual a linha de comando que você está executando?

Comment: A mensagem de erro é "could not be **found**" ou "could not be **loaded**"? (O título diz uma coisa e a pergunta diz outra!)

Comment: Realmente digitei errado no titulo. É "could not be loaded"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme o manual em http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html

> From your application directory, run:
>
> `Console/cake hello`

Ou seja, **a partir do diretório de sua aplicação**.

Então, primeiro vá para o diretório da aplicação, e depois tente novamente:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/cakephp/apps/almofadagram
./Console/cake hello
```

Comment: O ubuntu me retorna: `-bash: ./Console/cake: Permission denied`

Comment: Aliás, não entendi. Se vou no diretório e rodo `cake` ele roda(Não o script, mas o comando cake).

Comment: Bom, dei a permissão 755  a `cake` que não tinha feito. Agora executa. Mas agora deu outro problema, vou tentar resolver.

Comment: Bom, agora estou com problemas de permissão. Quando rodo ele com `sudo` O hello Word funciona, ou seja, o script roda. Mas quando uso sem sudo, ele da erro. Que tipo de permissão devo dar?

Comment: Veja http://stackoverflow.com/a/8879796/370290 e http://stackoverflow.com/a/17686488/370290

Comment: Na raiz do cake (`cd /home/ubuntu/cakephp`) execute `sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data .` (baseado na sugestão em http://stackoverflow.com/a/8879796/370290)

Comment: O ideal é fazer uma **nova pergunta** informando o **erro exato** que está aparecendo agora - trata-se de **outro problema**. (Recomendo também aceitar esta resposta, assim eu ganho uns pontinhos e fico motivado para ajudar mais!) ;-)

Comment: Descobri o problema, como eu testei com root, o CakePHP criou dois arquivos, dentro de `/tmp/cache/persistent`, então como esses dois arquivos pertenciam ao usuario root, quando eu rodava ele dentro de outro script com `exec` ele me retornava erro de permissão. Deletei esses dois arquivos, e rodei o script novamente, aonde ele criou novamente esses dois arquivos pertencente a `www-data`

Comment: E tudo certo. Agradecido.